# Count Indicators in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, indicator

I currently have indicators throughout a report based on the comparison of two cells.

```
Example:
| Indicator  |  Score 1  |  Score 2  |

|Green Arrow |     5     |     3     |
| Red Arrow  |     2     |     4     |
|Yellow Line |     10    |     10    |
```

My goal is to show at the end of the report how many green arrows, red arrows, and yellow lines. How would I be able to display the count of the arrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**For Green Arrows**

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Score1.Value>Fields!Score2.Value,1,0))
```

**For Red**

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Score1.Value<Fields!Score2.Value,1,0))
```

**For Yellow**

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Score1.Value=Fields!Score2.Value,1,0))
```

The `Sum` function sums by one every time it finds that `Score1` is greater than `Score2` for the green arrows case.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It makes sense to not really count the arrows but to count when the statement that makes the arrow appear green in the first place is True. That works perfect for me. Thank you.